# Prove that the following limit exists and is finite.

Tags: calculus, integration, functional-analysis

Let $f: (0, \infty)\to\mathbb{R}$ be a function that admits the antiderivative $F$ which has the propery that the limit of $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} F(x) $ exists and is finite.

a. Give an example of such a function for which $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} xf(x) $ does not exist.

b. If $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} xf(x) $ does exist, show that it is equal to $0$.

**What I have tried**

I'll only talk about the first requirement, the one at a., as it did not get past it.
In order for $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} xf(x) $, I have tried thinking of the funtion $f(x) = \frac{\sin(x)}{x}$, so that the limit is equal to $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow \infty} \sin(x) $, which does not exist. However, I am stuck on proving that the limit of the antiderivative of $f(x)$ exists and is finite. I have managed to prove that it is greater than zero ($\frac{\sin(x)}{x}\geq \frac{-1}{x}$, so it's clear).

Comment: You have not proven that it is greater than zero, since $\sin(x)/x$ does not satsify that $xf(x)$ has a limit. The fact that it is greater than or equal to $-1/x$ does not seem to be relevant in any way...

Comment: This should be a duplicate of something like $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ existing but $\lim_{x \to \infty} xf'(x)$ not existing or something?

Answer (score 1):

One antiderivative of the function $\frac{\sin(x)}{x}$ is the integral sine
$$
\operatorname{Si}(x):= \int_0^x \frac{\sin(t)}{t} dt
$$
The limit at infinity can be found by using Feinmann trick see e.g. [this](https://web.williams.edu/Mathematics/lg5/Feynman.pdf)

For the second point i will give an hint:

If $\lim_{x \to \infty } x f(x) \ne 0$ than, for $x$ big enough you will have
$$
f(x) \ge C \frac{1}{x}
$$
What happen if you integrate both sides?